# QgsVectorLayerExporter writing either geometry column or attribute table, not both

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to save a WFS layer to a Postgis database with no success. Somehow modifying the connection string I can get QgsVectorLayerExporter to write either the geometry column or the attribute table, never both.

So with these commands...

```
con_string = """dbname='gis' host='localhost' port='25432' user='qgis' password='qgis'
key='id' type='CURVEPOLYGON' table="public"."my_layer_new" (geom) """

QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer(my_layer, con_string, 'postgres', project.crs())
```

... I see the geometry column in the `views.geometry_columns` table and the `my_layer_new` table is created but it is empty.

However if I remove the `(geom)` from the connection string...

```
con_string = """dbname='gis' host='localhost' port='25432' user='qgis' password='qgis'
key='id' type='CURVEPOLYGON' table="public"."my_layer_new" """

QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer(my_layer, con_string, 'postgres', project.crs())
```

... no geometry column is in the `views.geometry_columns` table but on the otherhand the `my_layer_new` table is created and populated with the attributes of each feature.

This really feels like it's an *just add this string to X* type of situation.

**EDIT:**

After changing the last lines to

```
    err = QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer(my_layer, con_string, 'postgres', project.crs())
    print(err)
```

I discovered that the actual problem is `ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiSurface) does not match column type (CurvePolygon)`

Answer (score 2):

In the end creating an instance of `QgsVectorLayerExporter` and passing it the desired geometry type helped.

```
con_string = """dbname='gis' host='localhost' port='25432' user='qgis' password='qgis'
key='id' table="public"."my_layer_new" (geom)"""
exporter = QgsVectorLayerExporter(con_string, 'postgres', fields=my_layer.fields(), crs=project.crs(), overwrite=True,
                              geometryType=QgsWkbTypes.MultiSurface)
exporter.addFeatures(my_layer.getFeatures())
```

I wonder if this would have been possible with `QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer()` and passing the desired geometry type through `options`, but unfortunately this was not documented so did not give it a go.